# App crashes after changer theme to Wallpaper.NotTitleBar

Tags: java, android, user-interface, themes

I have tried a number of thing to change my app's theme to Wallpaper.NoTitleBar which all prove futile.

1. Modifying the styles file produces error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library"
2. When changing programmatically using code

   ```
   @Override
   public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
       Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme();
       theme.applyStyle(R.style.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar, 
       true);
       return theme;
   }
   ```

   "Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" does not appear in the pop up list of theme to choose from.
3. Using following line of when in the oncreate 
    setTheme(R.style.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar;
   produces not results.
4. Finally changing the manifest file created all sort of trouble for me and also produces error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library"

Comment: If you provide backward compatibility, you should use AppCompat theme

Comment: I'm willing to sacrifice backward compatibility for the use of Wallpaper.NoTitleBar theme. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Make sure your Activity derives from Activity and not AppCompatActivity.  But you give up most of the support library in the process.  Its almost certainly the wrong choice, and there's almost assuredly an AppCompatActivity compatible theme you should use instead.  Or make a custom theme that descends from the Theme.AppCompat but sets the same things that the Wallpaper.NoTitleBar does.